# Changing JAVA_HOME in cmd temporarily doesn't change PATH temporarily in windows

Tags: windows, command-line, java, path, jdk

I hava defined `JAVA_HOME` to jdk11 in users' environment variable and `PATH` contains `%JAVA_HOME%/bin` in it.

Now I want to switch to jdk8 temporarily in command-prompt (`cmd`) by changing `JAVA_HOME` to jdk8 but it doesn't change value in `path` or `java -version` doesn't change in current instance of cmd.

P.S.- I have deleted c:\Program Data\Oracle\java.. files to be avoid any confusion

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### It doesn't change value in path or java -version doesn't change in current instance of `cmd`

You have to restart `cmd` for the changes to take effect as a `cmd` shell inherits it environment from the parent process.

---

#### So what is the correct way to switch between Java versions from the command line?

Use a set of batch files, as follows:

> Being a Java developer, I always compile and test my code on different Java versions. But switching between them is a huge problem. So finally I found an easy method to do this. You have to create following batch files and place them in directory you open your command line in or in SYSTEM PATH. You can use you favorite text editor to create these files.
>
> jdk14.bat
>
> ```
> @echo off
> echo Setting JAVA_HOME
> set JAVA_HOME=C:\j2sdk1.4.2_12
> echo setting PATH
> set PATH=C:\j2sdk1.4.2_12\bin;%PATH%
> echo Display java version
> java -version
> ```
>
> jdk15.bat
>
> ```
> @echo off
> echo Setting JAVA_HOME
> set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_12
> echo setting PATH
> set PATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_12\bin;%PATH%
> echo Display java version
> java -version
> ```
>
> jdk16.bat
>
> ```
> @echo off
> echo Setting JAVA_HOME
> set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_11
> echo setting PATH
> set PATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_11\bin;%PATH%
> echo Display java version
> java -version
> ```
>
> Make sure you assign the appropriate `JAVA_HOME` value in batch files, according to your Java installation. Whenever you want to switch between Java versions, just run the respective batch file and you are done.
>
> Note:  `JAVA_HOME` and the path to java must always refer to the exact same version of the `JDK`. If you mix them up, unpredictable things will happen!

Source [Switch between different JDK versions in Windows | Oracle Pranav's Blog](https://pranavprakash.net/2008/12/07/being-java-developer-i-always-compile/)

Comment: but on restarting the temporary value of JAVA_HOME will be lost

Comment: You have to set it permanently and then change it back when you are done.

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: I have already tried the method shown here before coming to this page since I visited the referenced link before.  Unfortunately this didn't work. I am using Window 7 Enterprise. And also I tried this PowerShell method https://dzone.com/articles/using-multiple-versions-jdk. No luck.

Comment: @dush Then you are doing something wrong. Please ask a new question.

Comment: @DavidPostill, My question is almost the same. Therefore I started it over again, cut and paste above code in jdk16.bat and changing only JAVA_HOME and PATH to jdk version folder and its bin. My only difference is I have jdk1.7 an jdk1.8. Same result.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that the variable reference in `PATH` is expanded at the time of the assignment to `PATH`, any later changes are ignored, the reference to the original value is lost. It's like making a copy of the value of the variable, not creating a reference to the variable.

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\dir1
PATH=%JAVA_HOME%
set JAVA_HOME=C:\dir2
PATH
```

This will output `C:\dir1` (value of `JAVA_HOME` at the time of the assignment) and not `%JAVA_HOME%`.

You need a script like this to call after a change to `JAVA_HOME`:

```
PATH=%JAVA_HOME%;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;...
```

Answer (score 0):

I know the answer is a bit late but the accepted one did not work for me so I changed the code a bit and ended up with the following solution which worked for me:

```
@echo off
echo Setting JAVA_HOME
setx -m JAVA_HOME "C:\Java\jdk-1.7.0_80"
echo setting PATH
setx -m PATH "%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%"
echo Display java version
java -version
```

`setx -m` changes the **system** variable but If you need to change the user variable just leave out this parameter. As the script needs to be executed with administrator privileges I stored the script at the %user_home% location and created a shortcut to it. The shortcut can be placed wherever you want. One thing you need to change at the shortcut properties: `Right-click the shortcut -> properties -> shortcut tab -> advanced -> run as administrator`. This solution worked perfect for me.